Create a model dynamically with create_model() specifying a subset of fields in Pydantic V2
We're able to create a new model dynamically using create_model() like this:
from pydantic import create_model

base_model = ...
new_model = create_model('MyNewModel', base_model)

The problem is that base_model may contain certain fields that I don't want them to be included in new_model.
Is there any solution to this in Pydantic V2?
